# Print clickable list of options in function in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm working on something like a chatbot, I'm reading the user's input fine at the moment.
But I want to print a list of options for the user after choosing one of the options and will display some content/text in the text/display box:

For example:
If the user types in (Menu), it will print a list of clickable menu:

1. Name
2. Age
3. Date

So the above list should be clickable, and when the use click on (1. Name), it will display a value like (John). And so on...

```
function Menu(x) {
  document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0].innerHTML += "1. Name\n";
  document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0].innerHTML += "2. Age\n";
  document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0].innerHTML += "3. Date\n";
}
```

or using:

```
document.getElementById("textarea").innerHTML = "Hello World\n";
```

Comment: Sorry, what is the specific question?

Comment: How to print a list of clickable options by calling a function? So let's say I have the above function, and when I call it somewhere in my code like Menu(); it will run fine but what I got is only text. I want to make this text clickable so when you click 1. Name for example it will display a value such as (John). and when you click (2. Age) it will display (29 years old). and so on..

Answer (score 1):

I tried to understand what you are trying to achieve and I can come up with the following solution first of all text can not be clickable that's why I'm going to use select in order to show you the way and you can also use another way like buttons on links to achieve that but let show some.

```js
let time = new Date()
let name = 'John';
let age = 29;
let date = time.getDate() + '-' + time.getMonth() + '-' + time.getFullYear();
const select = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
let show = document.getElementById('show');
select.onchange = () => {
  console.log(select.value)
  if (select.value == 'name') {
    show.textContent = name;
  } else if (select.value == 'age') {
    show.textContent = age;
  } else if (select.value == 'date') {
    show.textContent = date;
  } else {
    show.textContent = '';
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #8080ffff;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 40%;
  height: 40%;
  border: 1px solid cyan;
  text-align: center;
}

select {
  grid-row: 2;
  width: 170px;
  height: 30px;
}

#show {
  grid-row: 3;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <select>
    <option></option>
    <option value="name">name</option>
    <option value="age">age</option>
    <option value="date">date</option>
  </select>
  <div id="show"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not exactly what I wanted to be honest but it really helped me a lot :D I could use it to do my purpose. Thank you so much mate!